# Edit a vector in a for loop and printing it but it will not change

Tags: c++, vector, output

I have read in the data from a file and have given the user multiple options on what they are allowed to do one of which is to edit lines of data.
i created an infinite for loop that ends only when the user uses x or X when the edit option is chosen i have altered the vector but later on if i have user use the view option the vector seems unchanged

Why is it that although the vector is altered then asked to print out its info again alter on that it prints the older version of the vector but if you print the vector it shows its been altered

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
const int NCOLS = 4;
const int NROWS = 10;
void description_and_options(vector<vector<string>> data, int count[NCOLS]);
void view_line_data(int choice, vector<vector<string>>data);
void available_options();

int main()
{
    fstream file_name;//create the new file
    string user_input_file;
    vector<vector<string>>read_in_vector;


    string user_option_choice;
    string small_exit = "x";
    string large_exit = "X";
    int view_choice;
    int edit_choice;
    int counter[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 };
    string edit_row;
    string edit_username, edit_password, edit_notes, edit_decision;
    cout << "Enter the name of the input file: ";

    cin >> user_input_file;
    file_name.open(user_input_file.c_str());

    if (file_name.fail())
    {
        cout << "File failed to open" << endl;
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }

    **for (string line{}; getline(file_name, line);)
    {
        istringstream line_is{ line };
        vector<string> row{};
        for (string value{}; getline(line_is, value, ';');)
        {
            row.push_back(value);
        }
        read_in_vector.push_back(row);
    }
    file_name.close();

    cin >> user_option_choice;**

    for (int lcv = 0; lcv < 2;)
    {
        **if (user_option_choice == small_exit || user_option_choice == large_exit)
        {
            break;
        }**
        if (user_option_choice == "D" || user_option_choice == "d")
        {
            description_and_options(read_in_vector, counter);
            available_options();
        }/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////D
        **if (user_option_choice == "v" || user_option_choice == "V")
        {
            cout << "Enter line number you wish to view:" << endl;
            cin >> view_choice;
            view_line_data(view_choice, read_in_vector);
            available_options();
        }**
        if (user_option_choice == "e" || user_option_choice == "E")
        {
            cout << "Enter line number you wish to edit:" << endl;
            cin >> edit_choice;
            view_line_data(edit_choice, read_in_vector);
            cout << "WARNING:   You cannot use semi-colons in these fields. Any semi-colons entered will be removed." << endl << endl;

            //cout << "Enter a line description: " << endl;
            **getline(cin, edit_row);**
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter a line description: " << endl;
            **getline(cin, edit_row);**
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter a username: " << endl;
            **getline(cin, edit_username);** 
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter a password: " << endl;
            **getline(cin, edit_password);**
            cout << endl;

            cout << "Enter notes: " << endl;
            **getline(cin, edit_notes);**
            cout << endl;

            cout << "You have entered:" << endl;
            cout << "Row Desc:  " << edit_row << endl;
            cout << "Username:  " << edit_username << endl;
            cout << "Password:  " << edit_password << endl;
            cout << "Notes: " << edit_notes << endl << endl;
            cout << "Is this the data you wish to add (Y/N)?    ";
            cin >> edit_decision;
            if (edit_decision == "N" || edit_decision == "n")
            {
                cout << "Line was not changed." << endl;
                description_and_options(read_in_vector, counter);
            }
            if (edit_decision == "Y" || edit_decision == "y")
            {
                file_name.open(user_input_file.c_str());
                //edit_line(read_in_vector , edit_choice, edit_row, edit_username, edit_password, edit_notes);
                **read_in_vector[edit_choice][0] = edit_row;
                read_in_vector[edit_choice][1] = edit_username;
                read_in_vector[edit_choice][2] = edit_password;
                read_in_vector[edit_choice][3] = edit_notes;
                cout << read_in_vector[edit_choice][0];**
                file_name << read_in_vector[edit_choice][0];
            }

        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');
        cin >> user_option_choice;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
void description_and_options(vector<vector<string>>data, int count[NCOLS])
{
    for (int lcv = 0; lcv < 9; lcv++)
    {

        cout << count[lcv] << " ";
        cout << data[lcv][0] << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
void view_line_data(int choice, vector<vector<string>>data)
{
    choice = choice - 1;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Row Desc:  " << data[choice][0] << endl;
    cout << "Username:  " << data[choice][1] << endl;
    cout << "Password:  " << data[choice][2] << endl;
    cout << "Notes: " << data[choice][3] << endl << endl;
}
void available_options()
{
    cout << endl << "   AVAILABLE OPTIONS" << endl << endl;
    cout << "D - DISPLAY LINE DESCRIPTIONS" << endl;
    cout << "V - VIEW LINE DATA" << endl;
    cout << "E - EDIT LINE DATA" << endl;
    cout << "A - ADD  LINE DATA" << endl;
    cout << "S - SAVE AND ENCODE FILE" << endl;
    cout << "X - EXIT PROGRAM" << endl;
}
```

output 
Row Desc:       Dragcave.net

Username:       Dragonmaster27

Password:        DragonM27

Notes:   Notes: username shortend

WARNING:   You cannot use semi-colons in these fields. Any semi-colons entered will be removed.

Enter a line description:
Dragcave.com

Enter a username:
Dragonmaster27

Enter a password:
DragonM27

Enter notes:
Notes: username shortend

You have entered:
Row Desc:       Dragcave.com
Username:       Dragonmaster27
Password:       DragonM27
Notes:  Notes: username shortend

Is this the data you wish to add (Y/N)? y

Dragcave.com

as you can see dragcave.net became .com but if you run through and print out using the V code it shows .net still

Comment: You're functions are actually modifying a copy of the vector.  You have to pass the vector's address to modify it(`void view_line_data(int choice, vector<vector<string>>& data)`)

Comment: Useful reading: [What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)

Comment: Off topic: Save yourself some code. Use a `char` instead of a `string` for `user_option_choice` and then `user_option_choice = tolower(user_option_choice);` now you only have to `if (user_option_choice == `d`)`

Comment: Please post just the relevant part of the code. This will help you gain more views for your question and answers for your question.